# How to reset stdin after an EAGAIN error?

Tags: mmap, stty

This is an error that I encountered in a large ruby script. I've managed to boil it down to what seems like the essence of the problem. In discussing this problem, the script was run by someone on OS/X without encountering the same  problem, so rather then a ruby problem it would seem to be a linux problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "io/console"


def read_char
  state=`stty -g`
  `stty raw -echo`
  input = $stdin.getc.chr
  input << $stdin.read_nonblock(3) rescue nil
  return input
 ensure 
  `stty #{state}`
  # Have also tried `stty -raw echo` 
end

system("strace -o strace.log ./trace the start")
puts "press a cursor key"
c=read_char
system("strace -o strace2.log ./trace regular key")
puts "press a regular key"
c=read_char
system("strace -o strace3.log ./trace cursor key")
puts "done press return to exit"
```

Things to mention about this code for non Rubyists, `<<` appends to an array **[1]**.

Backticks act pretty mush the same as in `sh`. At the moment, I do not know how Ruby specifically implements `read_nonblock`. I am digging into it. Will mention it if the question is still unanswered.

Later I will post the C++ source to the "trace" function but it is easy to understand without the source. Read the command-line and write to a predetermined file. Then ask for input. After reading some input from STDIN save it to the same file and exit. It is essentially a debugging function which temporarily replaces some more complicated functions.

**The problem**

The third system call behaves inappropriately, sort of like it was receiving it's input from `/dev/zero`.

The log entries for the reads from STDIN look like:

```
strace.log:read(0, "1\n", 1024)                = 2
strace2.log:read(0, "2\n", 1024)               = 2
strace3.log:read(0, 0x7fb388ba0000, 1024)      = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

So why is the third trace reading memory mapped IO?

The entry for the command which allocated the memory is:

```
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb388ba0000
```

Why is the `mmap` command taking an `fd` of -1 as an argument? **[2]**

**Additional Comment.** Based on what I've described so far, I pretty much have to conclude that when the EAGAIN error happens, something is not properly clean up, or the stdin state is somehow messed up, and now stdin is clogged. THat this then gets inherited by the system command. Thus the title question: how do you reset stdin, so that it behaves as it did so initially.

**[1]** Yeah as a C++ programmer I understand how this can be annoying.

**[2]** I'm not that familar with Unix memory mapped IO never having written anything using it myself. Windows memory mapped IO I did use a long time ago.

Comment: This is rather for stackoverflow. Furthermore I think the title doesn't fit the question well.

Comment: Actually I think the title does fit well. I am adding a comment that explains it. I sim0ply forgot to tie them together.

Comment: As for b eing more for stackoverflow, well the comment will address that but it seems to be more of a linux system calls problem then a programming peroblem, note the fact that the problem is not seen on OS/X but is on Linux.

Comment: See this reference: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314/unix-c-api-calls-ontopic . Looking at the close votes I would expect your question to be moved to SO soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mmap()` takes `-1` as file descriptor as the flag `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is given.

[`MAP_ANONYMOUS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) gives a zero initialized buffer. No file is read.

Thus it gives a r/w region of 4096 zero initialized bytes at address `0x7fb388ba0000`.

---

Update. OK, had a further look at it.

Most likely `stdin` is left with `O_NONBLOCK` after `$stdin.read_nonblock(3)`.

Not sure how to unset or prevent this with *conventional* ruby I/O functions, you can however fix it by using `fcntl`. So, in Ruby something like this:

```
require 'fcntl'

def read_char
    ...
ensure
    flags = $stdin.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL, 0)
    $stdin.fcntl(Fcntl::F_SETFL, (~Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK) & flags)
end
```

---

In C one could do something in direction of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

...

char buf[32] = {0};
int fd, flags;

fd = fileno(stdin);
if (fd == -1) {
     perror("fileno");
     return 1;
}

flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);

if (flags & O_NONBLOCK) {
    flags &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
}

if(!(fgets(buf, 32, stdin)) {
    if (ferror (stdin))
        perror("fgets");
}

...
```